# ¿Como puedo centrar mis componentes con GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, layout

La idea es que los componentes me queden como en la tercer imagen donde estan las dos lineas.Por que mis componente se ponen uno al lado del otro?Aca dejo como pensaba que habia que interpretarlo

```
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;this.add(label1,gbc);
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=0;this.add(text1,gbc);
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=1;this.add(label2,gbc);
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=1;this.add(text2,gbc);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tambien el *constraints* por cada componente agregado... `this.add(label1,gbc);  this.add(text1,gbc);` etc.

Comment: me olvide de pasarlo al codigo que puse aca,ahora lo edito.Lo tengo tal cual decis vos pero me aparecen en el medio de la pantalla y no en la posicion ue yo quiero

Comment: tengo puesto que quiero que empiece en la columna 0 y fila 0,tendria que aparecer arriba de todo a la izquierda,no?